# How to prevent user from creating new content until currently created content is verified by admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So i have this CreateShopView a view for seller type users to simply register their shops. the Shop model has a status field which is set to 'processing' by default, and obviously i didn't include the field in my ShopCreateForm so every time a seller registers a shop it's saved in the database with the status of 'processing'.
my question is how can i prevent sellers from registering new shops while they still have a shop with 'proccesing' status. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not even want to allow the user to get to the form then!

Something along those lines in your view.py should work:

```py
from django.contrib import messages

def new_shop(request):
  shop = Shop.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()

  if shop:
    if shop.status == 'processing':
      messages.add(request, messages.ERROR, 'Your last shop has not been approved yet.')
      return redirect('shop:overview') # redirect the user and display error message

  # render the form here
```